# How can I select cases based on time data?

Tags: r

I am new to using R and I'm stumbling upon a few problems which I can't seem to solve on my own. I can't figure out how I can select cases based on time units.

I want to select cases where `Time_D` - `Time_A` is equal or above 5 seconds (for the same individual).

For instance my data frame consists of the following data:

```
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+
|   | Individual    | Time_A       | Time_D        |  
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+
| 1 | A             | 09:21:27     | 09:21:28      |     
| 2 | A             | 09:21:29     | 09:21:40      |   
| 3 | A             | 09:21:30     | 09:21:36      |   
| 4 | B             | 09:32:14     | 09:32:23      | 
| 5 | B             | 09:32:18     | 09:32:22      | 
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+
```

And I want to only select the cases where `Time_D` - `Time_A` >= 5 seconds to get the following data frame:

```
+----------------+------------+-------------+
|   | Individual | Time_A     | Time_D      |   
+----------------+------------+-------------+
| 2 | A          | 09:21:29   | 09:21:40    |    
| 3 | A          | 09:21:30   | 09:21:36    | 
| 4 | B          | 09:32:14   | 09:32:23    | 
+----------------+------------+-------------+
```

I have already coded for time:

```
DT <- as.data.table(df3)[, Time_A := as.ITime(Time_A)][, Time_D := as.ITime(Time_D)]
```

Answer (score 0):

After converting the columns to `ITime` you can subtract `Time_D` - `Time_A` and keep rows where the difference is greater than 5.

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c('Time_A', 'Time_D')
setDT(df)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.ITime), .SDcols = cols]
df[(Time_D - Time_A) >= 5]

#   Individual   Time_A   Time_D
#1:          A 09:21:29 09:21:40
#2:          A 09:21:30 09:21:36
#3:          B 09:32:14 09:32:23
```

---

In base R, you can do this with `as.POSIXct`.

```
subset(df, as.POSIXct(Time_D, format = '%T') - 
           as.POSIXct(Time_A, format = '%T') >= 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   filter(period_to_seconds(hms(Time_D)) - period_to_seconds(hms(Time_A)) >=5)
#  Individual   Time_A   Time_D
#1          A 09:21:29 09:21:40
#2          A 09:21:30 09:21:36
#3          B 09:32:14 09:32:23
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Individual = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
      Time_A = c("09:21:27", 
"09:21:29", "09:21:30", "09:32:14", "09:32:18"), Time_D = c("09:21:28", 
"09:21:40", "09:21:36", "09:32:23", "09:32:22")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```